# Where to find CD/DVD driver inside Device manager?

Tags: drivers

For some reason, I upgraded my windows vista to 7 on my acer aspire 5520. The CD/DVD device was missing from my computer. Articles told me to go in device manager and uninstall the device and restart so windows can reinstall it for me.

Where in device manager is this driver? Under what category will I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a category for CD/DVD drives in Device Manager, unless Windows thinks you don't have any CD/DVD drives installed in the computer (which is probably the case if you're having trouble locating its device category in Device Manager).

Check to be sure that a cable isn't loose, the drive is not broken or disabled in the system BIOS settings.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a category name titled "DVD/CD-ROM drives" and if you double-click on it, or if you click on the plus sign next to it, you should see your device name.

**Windows XP**:

[image: rev 2 of G5maD]

**Windows Vista**:

[image: rev 2 of 6VFKG]

Answer (score 0):

If the drive doesn't appear in the location shown in the photos, you can try adding a piece of hardware manually. See http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/tips/addhwwizw7.mspx for details.

Comment: If it doesn't appear automatically, adding it manually isn't going to work. Those directions are really meant for pre-PNP devices, which this is not.

Comment: yes/no, sometimes pnp doesn't recognise devices.

Comment: The instructions given on that page do not apply. They are for installing a device driver, not for manually installing the device itself. The effect of this is that the device would be auto-installed and configured the first time it's connected, using previously installed drivers.

Comment: Make note of step 4 which says that one should select "Show all devices". This will make the wizard prompt you for a disk (installation disk) to install a driver. This relies on using "Add Hardware Wizard" (Hdwwiz.cpl on Windows Vista or Hdwwiz.exe on Windows 7 and later). Instead of "Show all devices" one should select proper device category. In other words, it's useless to install a driver for a device that's not being recognized. It will never be used. Besides, you would need to have that driver, and as far as CD/DVD devices go these use generic Microsoft drivers and are auto-configured.